# c++ type conversion class member operator issue

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion, operator-keyword, member

There are two simple classes:

```
class X
{
    int value;

public:

    X() : value(0) {};

    X(int v) : value(v) {};

    X(const X& x) {     // Does not help!
        this->value = x.value;
    }

    X(const X&& x) noexcept { // Does not help!
        this->value = x.value;
    }

    X& operator=(const X& right)  { // Does not help!
        this->value = right.value;
        return *this;
    };

    X&& operator=(const X&& right) noexcept  { // Does not help!
        this->value = right.value;
        return std::move(*this);
    };

    bool operator==(X& right) const {
        return this->value == right.value;
    };

};

class Y
{
    int value;

public:

    Y() : value(0) {};

    operator X() const {

        return X(this->value);

    };  // Y objects may be converted to X
};
```

And sample how I use it:

```
int main()
{

X x1, x2;
Y y1;

x1 = x2;   // Compiles (using the X& operator=)

x1 = std::move(x2);   // Compiles (using the X&& operator=)

auto newv = (X)y1; // Compiles 

x1 == newv;   // Accepted!

x1 == (X)y1;   // Error!!!

} // END: main()
```

x1 == (X)y1 line generates the error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'X' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

and "no operator == matches these operands, operand types are X==X

I try to compile it with C++17.

Whats wrong with it if line like "x1 == newv" is good for the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool operator==(X& right) const
```

should be

```
bool operator==(const X& right) const
//               ^^
```

otherwise it cannot be called with a temporary `X`, which `(X)y1` is.

https://ideone.com/tN1w8T

Another problem, which is unrelated to your compiler error from my comment:
`bool operator=(X& left) const` is this the comparison operator `==` or the assignment `=`? The function declaration is a mix and the implementation is clearly comparison.
Assignment would be `X& operator=(const X& left) {value = left.value; return *this;}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That means that (X)y1 is an temporary variable for the compiler and cannot be changed any way thus it cannot processed by the bool operator==(X& right) const because it can change "right". And there is not any problem to compile it if "right" is marked like const becouse it "const"? I try to understand why the compiler allowed it by auto variable.

Comment: `newv` is an `lvalue` and therefore can bind to an `lvalue reference`. `(X)y1` is an `rvalue` and cannot bind to an `lvalue reference`, only to a `const lvalue reference` or `rvalue reference`.
There is no problem with marking `right` as `const`, as it should never be changed during a comparison.

Comment: @newv Thus - any conversion operator is a rvalue? And only "auto" can convert a rvalue to the lvalue? I now that X&& can be left value, but newv marked in "watch" like the X type and not the X&& type.

Comment: https://www.internalpointers.com/post/understanding-meaning-lvalues-and-rvalues-c should explain it. You need to learn what an lvalue and an rvalue is.

Comment: It not explane the question. It's explain only r- and l-values.

Comment: There is a chapter `Const lvalue reference to the rescue` a little bit above the middle, which explains your problem. It does not matter if it is an `int` or `class X`.

Comment: Yes, it's correct about the main question. I only try to understand the nature of (X)y1 expression. Wich type is it? And wich type have "auto newv" is? For the compiler. Before we say that (X)Y is r-value that will be converted to l-value inside "auto". But inside the debug process I see that "auto variable" have X type. Was expected const X& or X&& by me.

Comment: `(X)y1` is an rvalue with the type `X`, `newv` is a variable of type `X` and in the context of `x1 == newv` an lvalue with type `X`. An lvalue can bind to a lvalue reference, but an rvalue can only bind to a const lvalue reference, both can bind to a rvalue reference (`X&&`).